# Iterating through a 2d vector with custom increment

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I am trying to iterate through a large 2D vector (2 mil entries) and obtain some sample data. I figured out a good way of doing that would be to randomly shift my iterator to a random column, assign a random increment and repeat this process for every row.

**Simplified Code**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    float _mean = 0;
    vector<vector<size_t>> v{ { 1,2,3 },{ 4,5,6 },{ 7,8,9 } };
    vector<vector<size_t> >::iterator row;
    vector<size_t>::iterator column;
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t shift, inc;
    for (row = v.begin(); row < v.end(); ++row)
    {
        shift = rand() % 10;
        inc = rand() % 6;

        for (column = row->begin()+shift; column < row->end(); column += inc) // row downshift
        {
            _mean += *column;
            ++i;
        }
    }
    cout << _mean/i << endl;
    system("pause");

}
```

The vector's size is not constant therefore, I can't really make it into a simple for loop without the use of iterators.

Also, I have identified, I think, the error that causes all this. *The iterator increments out of range*, but I still don't know how to (elegantly) fix it.

For **a large vector** the code **works** until it reaches the end of the row.
Do you have any suggestions that could help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it cache friendly if you iterate through every row subsequently?

Comment: Well in reality, I am sampling both rows and columns and it "works", up until the iterator reaches the end of the row/ column.

Comment: I would suggest using a random-shuffled index vector per row, picking a random number of indexes from that vector to obtain the row data as you're enumerating. rows. It isn't particularly cache-friendly, but I think you would probably be happier with the results, especially for larger matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

- you can't assume that the end iterator can be compared for less than another iterator. This works only for [random iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) (fortunately it's the case for vectors) and only if they are valid, i.e. within the bounds (which precisely isn't guaranteed in your code). So the for-condition should be `column != row->end()`.
- you risk to miss the end if `inc>1` and if you miss the exact value of the end iterator.

The easiest alternative would be:

```
   for (int column = shift; column < row->size(); column += inc) // row downshift
    {
        _mean += (*row)[column];
        ++i;
    }
```

***P.S.:*** * note that you could occasionally get an `inc` of 0 which would result in a infinite loop (see [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig)'s comment). Better determine it with:  `inc = (rand() % 5) + 1;`

Comment: @n.m. I've edited in the meanwhile to express my thoughts more precisely (with extra link on iterator categories).

Comment: The wheels also fall of the algorithm if the OP is unlucky enough to have `rand() % 6` result in `0`, which is entirely possible. The loop becomes infinite in that case.

Comment: @Christophe column and row are just iterators and, I think, you cannot use the assign operator or the methods begin() and end().

Comment: @WhozCraig excellent remark.  However OP expresses his question as if it where a general phenomenon and he seeds the random generator so that it's unlike to always yield 0.  I'll nevertheless add your remark.

Comment: @nikjohn I see; for this code to work you'd need `column` as `int`.  I've corrected the snippet to add the indirection for `row`.